# Viewport rendering with bpy is not using the correct shader

Tags: python

I have a blender scene set up with a script attached that rotates an object, renders an animation, saves the frames, then repeats:

```
import bpy
from math import radians
from mathutils import Euler

track = bpy.context.scene.objects["BezierCircle"]

for angle in range(8):
    angle = angle + 1
    # set output
    bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].render.filepath = 'C:/Users/Evan/Pictures/BlenderSprites/Angle' + str(angle) + '/'
    print(bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].render.filepath)
    # change camera angle
    new_angle = radians(angle*45)
    track.rotation_euler = Euler((0, 0, new_angle), 'XYZ')
    # change viewport settings
    view3d = None
    for area in bpy.context.screen.areas: 
        if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
            for space in area.spaces: 
                if space.type == 'VIEW_3D':
                    view3d = space
    print(view3d.shading.type)
    # render viewport
    bpy.ops.render.render(animation=True, use_viewport=True)
```

This part is working. However, the images produced are being saved using the "RENDERED" shading, not the "SOLID" shading that I have selected in the GUI, despite print(view3d.shading.type) outputting "SOLID".

I figure this may be because I'm using ops.render.render instead of ops.render.opengl, but ops.render.render uses the setup I already have configured, which is much nicer.

Is there any way to easily make ops.render.render use SOLID shading?

Answer (score 0):

Do not pass the  'use_viewport=True' argument while calling bpy.ops.render.render() function. Use bpy.ops.render.render(animation=True). Another error might be that you are not using keyframes for your animation. By using rotation keyframes, blender can animate in better ways.  For additional debugging, you can save the final output in a blend file. Open the blend file using GUI and you can understand what is going on.